# SAML signing certificate- your role does not have permissions required to manage signing certificates

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, spring-saml

Receiving the follow error while configuring. help me fix on this issue

SAML signing certificate- your role does not have permissions required to manage signing certificates

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: while integrating  Robin powered app , receiving the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure certificate you need to  Have one of the following  roles:

```
1)Global Administrator
2) Cloud Application Administrator
3)Application Administrator
4)owner of the service principal.
```

You need to have one of these permissions To delegate the update of the SAML token signature and sign-in algorithm for SAML based single sign-on applications

```
 1)microsoft.directory/applicationPolicies/basic/update
 2)microsoft.directory/applications/authentication/update
 3)microsoft.directory/servicePrincipals/policies/update
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-enterprise-app-permissions)